# CoreData, NSPredicate and fetchRequest puzzling behaviour - or is it just me?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have encountered an odd scenario when using CoreData, NSPredicate and fetchRequest.

My predicate is:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(status == %d) AND (watched == NO) AND (user_id == %@)", argumentArray: [Int(ItemStatus.Shortlisted.rawValue), false, userId])
```

If I run fetchRequest with the above predicate, I get 0 results. If I ***swap*** the `user_id` clause with `watched` clause, I get the expected result.

If I use NSCompundPredicate, with the individual clauses broken down to sub-predicates, using:

```
request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [subPredicate1, subPredicate2, subPredicate3])
```

The outcome is what I expect.

I am not clear why why is there a discrepancy between the three approaches.

Thoughts?

Comment: There are 2 placeholders (%d and %@), and 3 arguments ? `(watched == NO)`= > `(watched == %d)` since you put `false` in the arguments array.

Comment: Not sure I follow: I have three arguments "(status == %d) AND (watched == NO) AND (user_id == %@)" and 3 arguments in the array: [Int(ItemStatus.Shortlisted.rawValue), false, userId]

Comment: looking at Walt's answer, I assume you actually meant 'one parameter in the argument array will be ignored as you provided an actual value'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a guess, (My Core Data is a little rusty) it looks like you have specified 3 arguments in the argument array, but the predicate is only using 2 of them.

With (watched == NO), you've specified the value inline rather than with a "%" delimited format, so it won't use the "false" from the argument array.

Comment: I guess I need a break ... :) rookie's mistake. Tested and you were spot on. Did not even noticed it. This also explain why when breaking the expression down to 3 sub-predicates worked. Thanks!

Comment: Happens to all of us. No Worries.  It may be that Xcode would have warned you in Objective-C, but not Swift (yet.)